# How can I check the usage of a worker role's local storage resources?

Tags: azure

I've set up a local storage resource for my Azure worker role, but from C# code I see no way of checking how much space is available on a LocalResource object. How can I find this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the same way you'd see what's being used in a mounted drive. Unfortunately, you need to crawl the folder/directory structure and sum up all the various files sizes.

Comment: Drag, was hoping that it wouldn't come to that. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Where in the folder structure is the root of Local Storage? I've asked a separate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48486033/7850) about this.