# Where in the file system is a Worker Role's Local Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I've created a log file in a Worker Role, which is being stored in Local Storage.
Where in the file system of the instance can I find that log now? IOW, where is the root of Local Storage for a worker role?

Comment: Are you trying to find the path of local storage on your local computer or in an VM running your worker role code in Azure?

Comment: @GauravMantri on the VM running my worker role

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the path of the local storage, you can use [`LocalResource.RootPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.localresource.rootpath.aspx). This will give you the full directory path of the local storage resource.

For example:

```
try 
{

    LocalResource myConfigsStorage = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("local-resource-setting-name");

    string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(myConfigStorage.RootPath + "myFile.txt"); 
    //… do your work with s 
} 
catch (Exception myException) 
{ 
    …    
}
```

Please look under `C:\Resources` directory in the Azure VM running your Worker Role and you should be able to find the log file you created. Please note that Azure SDK creates folders inside this directory for your worker role instance id and deployment id.

Comment: I'm looking for simpler than that. I don't want to go through redeploying my cloud service with new code to discover where local storage is. What's the default? Like, `"C:\Somewhere\..."`

Comment: I don't think there's a default because the local storage directory changes everytime you make a new deployment as the path includes the deployment id and role instance id. But I believe it gets stored somewhere in `AppData/Local` folder.

Comment: So if you have Remote Desktop enabled on your VM, you can connect to the VM using that and look for the file you created in `AppData` folder.

Comment: Under which user folder? I can see `Default`, `Public` and `my-admin`. None of them show my log file, but at least I'd like to narrow down where it _should_ appear...

Comment: Sorry....My bad. I didn't have any cloud services deployed ATM so I told you to look under `AppData` folder as the local storage path for cloud services under emulator points to that directory. I looked up some old logs and it tells me that the local storage path is somewhere in `C:\Resources` directory. Can you please check there?

Comment: Yup, that's it. Specifically, under `C:\Resources\Directory`. Update your answer and I'll mark this the correct answer.

Comment: Updated my answer.